# Problem with ZipFile. Creates an additional subfolder?

Tags: python, data-science

I am using this example to extract an archived folder:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall()
```

The problem is that the files do not appear in the folder where the file.zip is located, but additional subfolders are created and the files are unpacked there.

*I am using Visual Studio Code.*

Comment: Is your goal to extract the zipfile to where the original zip is located? By default, `zipfile.extractall` extracts to whatever your current directory is (usually where you're running Python from).

Comment: Yea, but for some reason it creates subfolders. In my script path_to_zip_file = os.getcwd() + '/Data/file.zip.

Comment: Well, if your zipfile  has directories in it, it will also create those too when unpacking - do you just want everything flat decompressed into the `Data` directory? No directories or anything, just the files?

Comment: Just files from file.zip to Data folder :)

Comment: Okay, I see what you want now, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to flatten your ZIP file upon extraction (no directories, just the leaf files).

By default, [`zipfile.ZipFile.extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) will write the contents to whatever the current working directory is, and keep the original structure of whatever was put into the archive.

Instead, what we need to do here is examine the `ZipFile` itself and:

1. Find files that are actually files and not directories
2. Modify their metadata so they don't have full paths if they were originally stored under directories
3. Use [`ZipFile.extract`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) to write files out to a different directory

Let's create a zipfile with some nested directories and files inside them, in my working directory called `ziptest`.

```
pwd
# /Users/wkl/Downloads/ziptest
mkdir -p Data/t1/t2/t3
touch Data/t1/file1.txt
touch Data/t1/t2/file.txt
touch Data/t1/t2/t3/file3.txt

cd Data
zip files.zip -r t1

#  adding: t1/ (stored 0%)
#  adding: t1/file1.txt (stored 0%)
#  adding: t1/t2/ (stored 0%)
#  adding: t1/t2/file.txt (stored 0%)
#  adding: t1/t2/t3/ (stored 0%)
#  adding: t1/t2/t3/file3.txt (stored 0%)

rm -rf t1
```

After this, I just have a `files.zip` archive that contains the entire `t1` tree. Now, from my working directory, I have this script called `ziptest.py` which just extracts things:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path, PurePath
from zipfile import ZipFile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_dir = Path.cwd() / "Data"
    archive = data_dir / "files.zip"
    with ZipFile(archive) as zfile:
        # this flattens files by changing what
        # their output file would be
        for info in zfile.infolist():
            # skip any directories
            if not info.is_dir():
                # manipulate the zip info so that
                # we just have the filename, and no directories
                info.filename = PurePath(info.filename).name

                print(f"Extracting {info.filename} to {data_dir}")

                # extract lets you specify a path
                # to write the file to
                zfile.extract(info, data_dir)
```

If I run this script, I get this output:

```
> python3 ziptest.py
Extracting file1.txt to /Users/wkl/Downloads/ziptest/Data
Extracting file.txt to /Users/wkl/Downloads/ziptest/Data
Extracting file3.txt to /Users/wkl/Downloads/ziptest/Data

> ls Data
file.txt  file1.txt  file3.txt  files.zip
```

Note that if you have multiple files with the same name in the zipfile, this does not account for that.